# Using the Glide library to load image to fill up the screen

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am trying load a background Image using the glide library so that it fills up the whole screen. I have the following xml for the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   >

    <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <include layout="@layout/signup_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My code for in the activity in which I use the Glide library is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginscreen);

    // Setup the email field
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

    // Setup password field
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
Glide.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.green_field)
        .override(width,height)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageView);
```

After running the code the image has white spaces on the left and right of the screen but it fills up the whole height of the image. I have tried to use both .fitCenter() and .centerCrop() together but the Image become pixelated.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot fill the whole screen since you used

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

which orders ([docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean))):

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to
>   **preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable**.

Also this is buggy on pre API17 as above docs warn.

If you want to fill up whole screen you shall remove `android:adjustViewBounds` and perhaps consider using

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: you must be drunk, there is no centerFit scaleType

Comment: This worked perfectly, with height set to wrap content and width match parent, my images fit in perfectly with width and a dynamic height.